# Simple Liferay ProcessAction not working

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

Portlet Class

```
public class AddRoomController extends MVCPortlet {

    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)
            throws IOException, PortletException {
        System.out.println("hu to call thau chu...");
        super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }

    // @ProcessAction(name="addRooms")       //Adding this annotation also not solving the issue
    public void addRooms(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
            throws IOException, PortletException {
        System.out.println("Called");
        String locationName = actionRequest.getAttribute("locationName").toString();
        System.out.println("===> "+locationName);
        actionResponse.sendRedirect("addRooms.jsp");
    }
}
```

view.jsp

Snippet 1

```
<body>
<portlet:actionURL name="addRooms" var="addRoomsUrl"></portlet:actionURL>
<form action="${addRoomsUrl}" method="post">
<!-- Custom Inputs -->    
</form>
</body>
```

Snippet 2

```
<body>
<portlet:actionURL name="addRooms" var="addRoomsUrl"></portlet:actionURL>
<form action="<%=addRoomsUrl%>" method="post">
<!-- Custom Inputs -->    
</form>
</body>
```

I am trying to call action method using both above snippets but none of them works.

In my Portlet doView() is called but when I try to call processAction method name addRooms it is giving me error with null value. **I want to avoid use of alloy-ui if possible.**

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: What is the error/behavior you are getting? To me it seems `actionRequest.getAttribute("locationName")` is resolving to null and you are calling toString to it, which it doesn't like :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error got solved by using these:

1. Using actionRequest.getParameter(paramName)
2. Defining Portlet Namespace in Form Parameter Name